# Android layout getTag is null

Tags: android, layout

I noticed that  `android:tag`  is derived by the View class.
All  `Button, TextView`  and so on, are not inherited from  the View class.

As I look in the  view,

```
<TextView  
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:text="Services Demo" 
          android:tag="stxt"
          android:hint="stxt hint"
          android:gravity="center" 
          android:textSize="20sp" 
          android:padding="20dp"
     />
     <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:id="@+id/buttonStart" 
             android:text="Start"
             android:hint="Start button"
             android:tag="sbut1"
     />
```

I  detect the view looping through the structure or after an event 
I receive tag  back as  A NULL string.

```
String Tag= (String) textview.getTag()
```

As the tag Tag seems to  be intended to pass information from the layout to the application level, I start  to wonder.

Can anyone help me getting at the intended TAG, HINT, Description?

Comment: Firstly difficult 2 understand ur question i guess u are talking about view?? lemme knw if i am right

Comment: the tag is often used for the [Viewholder pattern](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/viewholder-pattern-caching-view-efficiently/). Never used tag from xml, so Idk how it works

Answer (score 1):

you need to set id and then call.

```
TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_id);

String Tag= (String) textview.getTag();
```